# Can I call wait on the same synchronized lock from another object?

Tags: java, multithreading, object, wait, notify

I would like to call a wait and notify on a different object than the one that has synchronized on a lock. Take this code for example:

```
Class1.foo() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        while(condition) { 
            try {
                lock.wait();
            }
        }
        lock.notify();
    }

}
```

I am wondering if this is equivalent to:

```
Class1.foo() {
    synchronized(lock) {
         Class2.bar(lock);
    }
}

Class2.bar(Object lock) {
    while(condition) {
        try {
            lock.wait();
        }
    }
    lock.notify();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can but this is classic cases of possible deadlocks.  You need to always make sure that all threads lock the locks in the same _order_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Monitors and synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) are *associated with objects*, not variables:

> *Every object has an intrinsic lock associated with it* .. A thread is said to own the intrinsic lock between the time it has acquired the lock and released the lock [as with synchronized] ..

In the given code, it can be seen that trivially inlining the method call in the latter case results in the same objects being used in the same sequence.

```
Class1.foo() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        while(condition) { 
            try {
                lock.wait();
            }
        }
        lock.notify();
    }
}

Class1.foo() {
    synchronized(lock) {
    // >> inline from Class2.bar(Object lock) {
    //    where lock evaluates to the same object
        while(condition) {
            try {
                lock.wait();
            }
        }
        lock.notify();
    // << end inline }
   }
}
```

The above only argues for equivalency in the presented code and makes no further claim. That is, it assumes that `Class2.bar` is only called from `Class1.foo` (or is otherwise synchronized upon the same object during the invocation).